# How to show several loops and doing stuff in it in a sequence diagramm?

Tags: loops, sequence-diagram

I want to show what my UserControl/Control  is doing when I plug a list of data in it, what happens when the user press certain keys, selecting text etc...

I feel somehow a sequence diagramm is not really suited for showing several loops and doing stuff within the loops.

Am I wrong or how can I cope with that case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a loop, then you have a series of operations that take place for all elements in the loop.

I would model the operations done in the loop as a sequence diagram by itself, if the operation in the loop are fairly complex.

I don't think we can have rules of thumb here, but when the process with the loop itself is complex, and the loop is relatively less complex, we can have them in a single sequence diagram.

If the process that has the loop is not very complex, but the loop is complex, then I would draw a sequence diagram for the operations of the loop and have a note that this entire sequence is called by a loop.

You can also have both sequence diagrams if needed.

**Update:**
We have to add some notes to the diagram because it is not straightforward to denote a "condition" in a sequence diagram.
The validate is part is something like

```
do validation
if validation succeeds
   proceed to next (business or other) logic
if validation fails
   feedback to user (or some other logic)

+----+          +----+          +----------------+      +----------------+
|User|          | UI |          | Your Validator |      | Business Logic |
+----+          +----+          +----------------+      +----------------+
  |     select     |                   |                        |
  |--------------->|   doValidation    |                        |
  |                |------------------>|----+                   |
  |                |                   |    | Validate          |
  |                |                   |<---+                   |
  |                |                   |                        |
  |                |                   | (validation fails:     |
  |                |  Validation Fail  |  feedback to client)   |
  |                |<------------------|                        |
  |                |                   |                        |
  |                |                   |                        |
  |                |                   | (validation succeeds:  |
  |                |                   |  proceed to            |
  |                |                   |  business logic)       |
  |                |                   |                        |          
  |                |                   |    someLogic           |
  |                |                   |----------------------->|
  |                |                   |                        |
```

**UPDATE 2**
*Why use sequence diagram in a case as mine?*
Because you still have to show the sequence of operations, and the developer still needs this information for coding :-)

With UML, as you probably already know, nothing is *imposed*. You are at your freedom to denote something in some fashion, provided your team also understands it the way you intended. These notes are also helpful.

I should have mentioned this before, some use an "option" fragment to denote a if else. This is more or less a note (I see it this way) but is perhaps more evident. I use them only when both the `IF` and the `ELSE` parts are both complex.

```
    +----+          +----+          +----------------+      +----------------+ 
    |User|          | UI |          | UI - Backend   |      |  Busines Logic |
    +----+          +----+          +----------------+      +----------------+
      |  Add Record    |                   |                        |
      |--------------->|  doinsertOrUpdate |                        |
      |                |------------------>|                        |
      |                |                   |      exists(record)    |
      |                |                   |----------------------->|
      |                |                   |                        |         
  ____|________________|___________________|________________________|__________
  |[Record exists]     |                   |                        |         |
  |   |                |                   |     Get Record         |         |
  |   |                |                   |----------------------->|         |
  |   |                |                   |                        |         |
  |   |                |                   |--------+               |         |
  |   |                |                   |        | Set UI Values |         |
  |   |                |                   |<-------+               |         |
  |   |                |                   |                        |         |
  |   |                |                   |   Update Record        |         |
  |   |                |                   |----------------------->|         |
  |   |                |                   |                        |         |
  |   |                | Send Message      |                        |         |
  |   |                |<------------------|                        |         |
  |   |                |  "Record found,   |                        |         |
  |   |                |   Updated"        |                        |         |
  |___|________________|___________________|________________________|_________|
      |                |                   |                        |
      |                |                   |                        |
______|________________|___________________|________________________|_________
| [Record does not     |                   |                        |         |
| exist]               |                   |                        |         |
|     |                |                   |--------+               |         |
|     |                |                   |        | Generate      |         |
|     |                |                   |        | Seqeuence     |         |
|     |                |                   |<-------+               |         |
|     |                |                   |                        |         |
|     |                |                   |   Create New Record    |         |
|     |                |                   |----------------------->|         |        
|     |                | Send Message      |                        |         |
|     |                |<------------------|                        |         |
|     |                |  "New Record      |                        |         |
|     |                |   Created"        |                        |         |
|_____|________________|___________________|________________________|_________|
      |                |                   |                        |
      |                |                   |                        |
      |                |                   |                        |
```

See [this](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm#Figure7EnrollingUniversity) for an example using an alt block.

Comment: How can I describe with a sequence diagramm, that the user IS selecting something and while selecting something I do validation?

Comment: You generally have a actor in the sequence diagram. The "Message" from the actor to the first class (would be the UI in your case) would be "Select an Item", for example

Comment: yes right, but DURING the selection a algorythm is started checking some chars WITHIN the selection/While the selection happens. How to describe this with a sequence diagramm?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have some sort of a list on a UI, and when the user selects one item from the list. when this selection happens, you do some validation/processing, and (probably) based on the result proceed with the next step. My explanation would fit this. Do I understand your scenario correctly?

Comment: yes thats my scenario. The next step would be allow the selection or restrict it on chars.

Comment: looks nice Nivas, one last question, where would set the Validation Succeed?

Comment: The "validation failed" is a message to send to the UI as feedback to the user. If the validation succeeded you would proceed with your next step, right? I have done a minor update to the note. It is not really possible to show condtions and branching in sequence diagrams. We have to live with notes.

Comment: and now the ultimate question, as you say "It is not really possible to show conditions and branching in sequence diagrams"... Why use it at all for such a case as mine?